# Linux unzip command: Option to force overwrite?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I am writing a shell script that unzips a ZIP file into an existing hierarchy of files, potentially overwriting some of the files.

The problem is that the unzip command asks for confirmation:
`replace jsp/extension/add-aspect.jsp? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y`

Is there an option to force unzip to overwrite the files?

Answer (score 491, accepted):

According to http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/ you can use the `-o` option to overwrite files:

```
unzip -o /path/to/archive.zip
```

Note that `-o`, like most of `unzip`'s options, has to go **before** the archive name.

Comment: e.g: ```unzip -o ZIP_PATH```, works as a modifier.

Comment: `-o` option should be used before any other arguments. Example: `unzip -o /path/to/archive.zip -d /destination_dir`

Comment: @FelikZ Thanks for the detail, I added your (stripped down) example to the answer

Comment: @loretoparisi What are you talking about? This is a Linux question. Are you looking for something like [Expand-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive)?

Comment: its showing `inflating: foldername/filename.php` @foraidt

Answer (score 70):

If you need to unzip in order to replace the new files only, you can use

```
unzip -f archive.zip
```

But for future reference, you can just type

```
unzip
```

and you will get a list of the arguments for this package.

The possible arguments, for this case, are:

```
-f  freshen existing files, create none
-n  never overwrite existing files         
-q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
-o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting
```

Use the one that you feel is more suited for your needs.

Comment: +1, I like the more subtle, friendlier version of "here's how to rtfm for context, but here's the relevant section of the m" approach.

Comment: Also looked at the help, but didn't understand the diff. between `-u  update files, create if necessary` and `-f  freshen existing files, create none` ‍♂️ ?

Comment: // , The difference is in the behavior if the file doesn't exist

Comment: @juanmirocks With -f, the newer files will not be extracted at all even if they are not on the destination (such as if a later version of the zip is created that has files that the previous unzip did not create). If you don't already know you want that, chances are you don't. On the contrary, -u will extract additional files not on the destination, ensuring nothing is missing from the destination which is in the zip.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
unzip -o <filepath/zipfile.zip> -d <path where you want files>
```

-o is replace existing file, best is use unzip --help